# Animations going beyond their programmed destination?

Tags: javascript, animation, nativescript

I am trying to animate a context menu in a Native script, so that on first tap, the child options jump out, and then when clicked a second time, they return. I hope my code below is fairly self-explanatory, if the button hasn't been clicked, then do the animation, if it has been clicked, then do the opposite.

```
exports.fabTap = function (args) {
   var google = page.getViewById("google");
   var facebook = page.getViewById("facebook");
   var amazon = page.getViewById("amazon");
   if (clicked == false) {
        google.style.visibility = "visible";
        facebook.style.visibility = "visible";
        amazon.style.visibility = "visible";

        google.animate({
                translate: { x: -55, y: -66 },
                duration: 500,
                curve: enums.AnimationCurve.cubicBezier(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1)
        });
        facebook.animate({
                translate: { x: 0, y: -75 },
                duration: 500,
                curve: enums.AnimationCurve.cubicBezier(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1)
        });
        amazon.animate({
                translate: { x: 55, y: -66 },
                duration: 500,
                curve: enums.AnimationCurve.cubicBezier(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1)
        });
   } else {
        google.animate({
                translate: { x: 55, y: 66 },
                duration: 500,
                curve: enums.AnimationCurve.cubicBezier(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1)
        });
        facebook.animate({
                translate: { x: 0, y: 75 },
                duration: 500,
                curve: enums.AnimationCurve.cubicBezier(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1)
        });
        amazon.animate({
                translate: { x: -55, y: 66 },
                duration: 500,
                curve: enums.AnimationCurve.cubicBezier(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1)
        });

   }
   clicked = !clicked;
}
```

However, as you can see from this animation, the buttons seem to go beyond (below) their original position. Any ideas why that is happening?

[image]

Update:

Thanks for pointing out that all animations are relative to the original base. However, if I change all my return translations to `translate: { x: 0, y: 0 }` then the visibility change seems to happen before the translation? Any idea how to get around that?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Lets take a look at **facebook.animate**; your first animation makes Y = Y - 75; So it moves up from the **base** location 75 pixels up.   Your second animation takes it and moves it to 75 pixels down from the **base** location.

So looking at the math:
Base facebook Location is 100\,100 
First animation animates it to  **BASE** - 75 = 100\,25; 
Second animation animates it to **BASE** + 75 = 100\,175

So the solution is simple; return them all to X:0 and Y:0; which is your starting location   No offset is your base location.

So each of the code blocks for return should be changed to: translate: { x: 0, y: 0 },

**Update:**
Element->Animation calls return a promise; The best way is to deal with visibility is to use the .then(function() { element.style.visibility = 'collapse'; }); so that way once the element has finished its animation it will then be hidden.

The other thing you could do is have the animation also have opacity = 0 at the end of the animation; so as it comes out it animates to opacity = 1; and as it returns it animates to opacity = 0.  Some animations this looks really nice having it fade in as it moves out and fades out as it returns.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I assumed that the translate moved the base. However, weirdly that new code has stopped the return animation from appearing? I assume its because the visibility change happens before the translation? Any ideas how to change that?

Answer (score 0):

The `animate()` method actually returns a `Promise` sou you can use the `then` callback to change the visibility after the animation has finished:

```
google.animate({ ... }).then(function(){
   google.style.visibility = "collapse ";
})
```